# Swapping columns of only some lines in bash

Tags: bash, awk, swap

I have a file whose columns are ordered with one logic on the upper half and another on the lowest, like

> *first half*
>
> locus_1 M1 -7.0056323 1 Locus_1 0.004335 1 M3
>
> locus_2 - 3.4194853 1 Locus_2 0.148344 1 M2
>
> locus_3 M5 -2.1111424 1 Locus_3 0.329310 1 M1
>
> *second half*
>
> locus_4 -4.2389254 1 - Locus_4 0.3219294 1 S2
>
> locus_5 -18.1941031 1 x Locus_5 0.0008329 1 M2
>
> locus_6 13.0201291 1 M4 Locus_6 0.0181229 1 -

I would like the first half to be printed `$1, $3, $4, $2, $5, $6, $7, $8` and the second half simply `$0`, so that they have the same order.

The $2 column of first half/$4 column of the second can contain a "-", an "x", a "M[1-5]" or a "S[1-5]", while the numbers of $3 first half/$2 second half can be positive or negative.

I wanted to do some `for` loop with `awk`, but I can't succeed in doing it... I use cygwin, if it can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link for Awk Built-in Variables:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
    if( NR<4 ){
    print $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " $2 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 " " $8
    }
    else{
    print $0
    }
}
```